# Why is the content cutting off in IE7?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

I am doing some browser testing on a sit under development. For the most part things look and work well, but on some of the content pages there appears to be something that obscures the content from the bottom of the browser window. This only happens in IE7. I have worked over the Developer Tools until my fingers are raw but still can't figure out what is causing the problem. If you grab the bottom of the IE7 browser window and move it up you can see the content gradually obscured.

Link to the page: `http://192.196.159.46/news/`

I would really appreciate some insight on resolving this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: runnning via chrome emulating ie7:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'attachEvent' sh117.html:2
run sh117.html:2
onload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `height: 100%` on the body tag. This is cropping the area in IE7.

When you define height=100% in IE7 on the body, it defines the height as the screen height, not the height of the content

Comment: Ok, so now I have a new challenge. If I remove height="100%" it breaks the sticky footer. How do I keep the sticky footer and show the content in IE7?

Comment: I am checking this a correct answer with the caveat that it breaks the sticky footer. I am opening another question to address this. Thanks for the help.